# Creating a Search Activity with launchMode="SingleTop"

Tags: android, android-activity, android-search

I have a SearchActivity that is from a search menu item with the following code:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

On the `manifest`, the search activity is declared as follows:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.Search"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".activity.Search" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

On the Search activity's `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()` methods, i handle the incoming intent but if i log the query, no matter how many times i change the query, it only shows the very first query made that launched the search activity.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Show the code that you use to "log the query" in `onNewIntent()`.

Answer (score 0):

try setting

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="@string/search_hint"
android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

this is a working code